# How to group by an integer column and sum up each row except for maybe the last row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 3 columns. The first 2 columns are `id` and `cost` which is an integer and float, respectively. The last column is a boolean flag, `omit`. The rows with the same `id` are already prearranged contiguously. All the rows have `omit = False`, there are some `id`s such that the last row has `omit = True`.

I want to compute a 4th column, `total_cost` that is the sum of the `cost` for each `id`, but it neglects the last row if `omit = True`.

Rather than checking for the `omit` flag for each row, I think it's faster to do a first pass that sums up all the cost and not account for `omit` and then subtract the last row for each vid if `omit = True`, so I use

```
df["total_cost"] = df.groupby("id")["cost"].transform("sum")
```

But I am not sure how to do the "subtract the last row for each vid if `omit = True`" part in a vectorized way?

Example:

```
id cost omit   total_cost
0  1.1  False  2.1
0  1.0  False  2.1
0  2.2  True   2.1
1  3.2  False  3.2
1  4.0  True   3.2
2  0.5  False  1.2
2  0.4  False  1.2
2  0.3  False  1.2
```

Comment: need example for answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to get all the last values of `omit` and `cost` and subtract them from the result when `omit` is `True`:

```py
last = df.groupby('id').agg('last')
out = df.groupby('id')['cost'].sum().sub(np.where(last['omit'], last['cost'], 0))
```

The alternative is to filter first:

```
out = df[~df['omit']].groupby('id')['cost'].sum()
```

For a small sample dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3],
    'cost':[100,25.0,33.0,45.0,50.5,10.8,120.3,40],
    'omit':[False,False,True,False,True,False,False,False]
})
```

The pre-filtering approach is about 2.5x faster on my machine. In both cases the output is the same:

```
id
1    125.0
2     45.0
3    171.1
```

Comment: interesting, I wonder if pre-filtering is faster in general for dataframes of all sizes. if it is, I'm surprised because I feel like pre-filtering adds more ops than no pre-filteirng

Comment: also, ideally I would like to assign the result to each row of `df`. I think yours outputs a dataframe that has length `len(df.id.unique())`. is there a quick way to resassign back to `df`?

Comment: @David You're adding a second `groupby`, a `sub` and a `where` versus a mask, so I'm not surprised it's slower. If you want to assign the values back, you can do `df['total'] = df[~df['omit']].groupby('id')['cost'].transform(sum); df['total'] = df['total'].fillna(method='ffill')` but it's simpler (and a bit better performance-wise) to use Panda Kim's answer.

Comment: ahh I forgot about the 2nd group by, though I wonder if it would be better if we just stored the result of the first groupby and reused it rather than groupby'ing again

Comment: @David true, you could do that. A quick test shows it's still about 1/2 the speed of the single operation though

Comment: yeah I think that might make sense too because storing the result may be costly as well

Answer (score 1):

There was no example in the text, so I used the example from the answer above.

**Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3],
    'cost':[100,25.0,33.0,45.0,50.5,10.8,120.3,40],
    'omit':[False,False,True,False,True,False,False,False]})
```

`df`

```
    id  cost    omit
0   1   100.0   False
1   1   25.0    False
2   1   33.0    True
3   2   45.0    False
4   2   50.5    True
5   3   10.8    False
6   3   120.3   False
7   3   40.0    False
```

**Code**

use `mask` and `groupby` + `transform`

```
df['total_cost'] = df['cost'].mask(df['omit']).groupby(df['id']).transform(sum)
```

`df`

```
    id  cost    omit    total_cost
0   1   100.0   False   125.0
1   1   25.0    False   125.0
2   1   33.0    True    125.0
3   2   45.0    False   45.0
4   2   50.5    True    45.0
5   3   10.8    False   171.1
6   3   120.3   False   171.1
7   3   40.0    False   171.1
```

Comment: I edited in an example to the OP but you have the right understanding. Your answer is what I want, but do you know how I can adapt the above answer to apply to all rows?